# How can I fix access to script blocked by CORS when redirecting from http to https with Angular?

Tags: angular, iis, cors

I have an SPA built in Angular 8.2 running on IIS 10.

Using the URL Rewrite module, I created a rule to redirect from http to https for the site

Here's the relevant portion of the web.config with the Angular SPA rewrite rules:

```
<rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url=".*" />
           <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
<rule name="HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

When I hit the root site using http://eqht-dev it redirects correctly to https://eqht-dev.

However, if I navigate to a sub module directly with http://eqht-dev/search, I am not redirected to https://eqht-dev/search.  Instead, I receive a CORS error:

```
Access to script at 'https://eqht-dev/runtime-es2015.58df40519ca9af120208.js' (redirected from 'http://eqht-dev/runtime-es2015.58df40519ca9af120208.js') from origin 'http://eqht-dev' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have attempted to add CORS module to the web.config:

```
<cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
    <add origin="http://eqht-dev" allowCredentials="true"/>
</cors>
```

But I get 403s when attempting to access the main page:

```
GET https://eqht-dev/runtime-es2015.58df40519ca9af120208.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
```

How can I properly redirect a call an http call to a sub-module to the relevant https submodule ( http://eqht-dev/search to https://eqht-dev/search)?

**UPDATE 2022.3.10**
I implemented @samwu suggestion below.  And while this does allow the site to function, it still does in http.  Calls to the backend api result in additional CORS error because the backend allows only calls from https.

Is this due to the submodules being structured like query strings?  I am going to attempt to add query string appending like in this: https://bobnoordam.nl/windows/iis-redirect-to-https-and-keep-your-query-string/.

UPDATE 2: 2022.3.10
Looks like this problem here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1046607/angular-and-iis-redirect-to-https-keeping-full-url

However, my config file matches theirs and it is still no bueno.

Answer (score 0):

Your https redirects are fine,you should try to resolve CORS errors. Try the following settings to enable cors in iis, merge this into the web.config file at the root of your application / site:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I added this.  And the site does run, but it is running as http, not the https.  And calls to my backend REST api are being blocked by CORS: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://eqht-api-dev/api/QhtDb/GetUsers' from origin 'http://eqht-dev' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`  I don't want to add the http version to my backend's CORS.  That seems like it defeats the point of https.

Answer (score 0):

After examining the link I posted above:https://serverfault.com/questions/1046607/angular-and-iis-redirect-to-https-keeping-full-url, I noticed that my rewrite rules were not in the same order that the were in that post.

Turns out rule order matters.  The HTTPS redirect rule has to come before the angular renaming rules.